# While an instance of a Scrapy spider is crawling, how can we dynamically change the DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting?

Tags: scrapy

**Objective:**

I want to send requests at a fast rate while I am getting banned and then once I get a 200 response I want the request rate to slow down. (I am doing this to test what IP addresses in a pool of proxy IP addresses are blacklisted for by a domain. And how many requests can be politely made from a good proxy IP.)

**`DOWNLOAD_DELAY` in `settings.py`**

In Scrapy, there is `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` settings that handles how fast requests are sent out.

**Question 1:** It appears that settings can not be changed after a spider is started?

```
ipdb> spider.crawler.settings.set('DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 3)
*** TypeError: Trying to modify an immutable Settings object
```

**Question 2:** Any suggestions on taking another approach?

Answer (score -1):

I get stuck here too, and figure out a quick and dirty way to solve it.

```
settings.fronzen = False
# change settings here
# e.g.   settings.set('REQUEST_HEADERS', {'authorization': 'hehe',}, priority=60)
# don't forget to set priority a integer larger than 40 to override `cmdline` priority
settings.freeze()
```